# API are only interface for referencing library classes or library classes themselves

Tags: api

I google this topic but I couldn't find the proper answer. I understand API as only Interface class that referencing library files to be used by other applications from other platforms. But someone told me that APIs are library files themselves.

I'm a novice to this topic so that suggest any answers to me, please.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an API is just a collection of interfaces. It is independent from implementation. Of course, usually, a standard implementation exists and is "associated" with the API but if the implementation is linked to the API, the API is not linked to the implementation.

If you take the example of Java, you'll notice that the API ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ ) only show protected and public fields/constructors/methods/... It is not showing private stuff.

The API is reduced to what is visible for the user which is somehow the definition of an interface. The implementation is hidden.

What might be confusing is that the API is generated from the implementation but that doesn't mean that the API is the implementation.

I might be wrong but I think things are usually going like this:

1. An private API is defined (it is specification, so, it can be source code or any descriptive file)
2. An implementation is developed based on the private API
3. A public API is generated from this implementation and is published
4. The implementation is published as a Framework / Toolbox / or whatever the name
5. Developers use the public API to build their application and they choose the best implementation (which is generally the one from which it was generated).

Fell free to comment if you disagree ;)